# react-native-google-mobile-ads not working with live key ios

Tags: react-native, expo, admob, react-native-google-mobile-ads, expo-ads-admob

I am using the same code my app is in production and the ads working fine till last week but now all of a sudden it stopped working I did not change anything there is no error when I run the app in development and also ad console is working fine. can you help me what can be the reason?

```
import React from 'react'
import {BannerAd, BannerAdSize, TestIds} from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads'

const adUnitId = 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy'

function App() {
return (
<BannerAd
  unitId={adUnitId}
  size={BannerAdSize.ANCHORED_ADAPTIVE_BANNER}
  requestOptions={{
    requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true
  }}
/>
)
}
```